# A game where starting with 3 boxes, with 10 balls in each, the goal is to remove as many balls as possible following the rules

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

This is a Norwegian olympiad problem:

> Peter has three boxes, with ten balls in each. He plays a game where the goal is to end up with as few balls as possible in the boxes. The boxes are each marked with a separate number: $4$, $7$, and $10$. It is allowed to remove $N$ balls from the box marked with the number $N$, put three aside, and put the rest of them in another box. What is the least possible number of balls the boxes can contain together in the end?
>
> - $0$ balls.
> - $2$ balls.
> - $3$ balls.
> - $5$ balls.
> - $6$ balls.

How should I solve this?

Is it trial, error what is this? I cant get any of the choices.

Suppose I choose $N = 10$ box. Then,

You transfer $7$ to get $7 + 10 + 10 = 27$ balls in the other two, sum.

But I can't get anything below $10$, how to do this?

Comment: Well, we can easily eliminate the $2$ and $5$ choices since we can only remove $3$ balls at each step and we start with $30$.

Comment: From which contest is this exercise ?

Comment: Norwegian Math Olympiad

Comment: We can also eliminate the $0$ option, since no matter which move you do, there must be at least one ball left over afterwards. That means it's either $3$ or $6$.

Comment: mmmm... difficult

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt, how do you know you only remove 3 balls at once?

Comment: For the record: the (relevant part of the) contest is over.

Comment: @Robart If I understood the question correctly, at each step we take $3$ balls and only $3$ balls away from the total sum, meaning that every total sum must be divisible by $3$ (since we start with $30$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the most elegant solution is to take all $10$ from the $10$-box and deposit the excess $7$ in the $7$-box. Then remove those $7$ and deposit the excess $4$ in the $4$-box. Then remove those $4$ and deposit the excess ball in the $10$-box. Now apply the same idea to the $7$-box: remove all $7$, deposit the excess $4$ in the $4$-box, immediately remove them, and deposit the excess ball in the $10$-box. Finally, remove the $4$ in the $4$-box and deposit the excess ball in the $10$-box. You now have $3$ balls in the $10$-box.

The key observation here is that you can reduce the contents of any box to a single ball (not necessarily in the same box) by depositing the excess balls in successively ‘smaller’ boxes.

Comment: Could we do the same starting with the 7-box instead of 10-box? Are you also using trail-and-error here? Thanks BrianM.Scott, you have been very helpful, and great!

Comment: @Robart: Yes, you could do it starting with any of the boxes; it just seemed most systematic to clear them from one end to the other. It wasn’t precisely trial and error. I noticed that if you made a move from one of the larger boxes, the number of excess balls was exactly the size of the move that you could make from the next smaller box. Pursuing that idea, I realized that this would let me reduce the contents of either of the larger boxes down to a single ball. \\ You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to end up with $3$ balls total (which is the minimum possible by the comments above): First take all the balls in the $10$-bin, put $3$ aside, and put the last $7$ into the $4$-bin. You now have $(17, 10, 0)$ balls.

Take $7$ balls from the $7$ bin, put three aside and the rest in the $4$-bin. You now have $(21, 3, 0)$ balls.

Take four balls from the $4$-bin, put three of them aside and the last one into the $7$-bin. Do this four more times. You now have $(1, 8, 0)$ balls.

Take $7$ balls from the $7$-bin, put three of them aside and the rest into the $4$-bin. You now have $(5, 1, 0)$ balls.

Lastly, take four balls from the $4$-bin, put three aside and one into the ten bin. There is now one ball in each bin, so you have $3$ balls left.

Comment: so this is trial-and-error? What if you started with taking balls out of the 7-bin?

Comment: @Robart What motivates your curiosity in starting taking balls out of the $7$- bin? The problem is solved here, and on a nice way (+1).

Comment: Yes, it's trial-and-error. The simplest and most straight-forward (although not always the easiest) way of proving that something is _possible_ is to actually do it. Proving that something is _impossible_, however, is never justified by trial-and-error, although some trial-and-error could help you discover a deeper pattern (like how you could never end up with $2$ or $5$ balls). As to what would've happened if I started in the $7$-bin? I might've succeeded, and then that's what I wouldve written. I might've failed, and then I would've tried something different next time.

Comment: @Arthur, but as an olympiad question, is it justified to have a trial-and-error question in such prestigious competitions?

Comment: Yes. At any point where an olympiad question asks "Is it possible to ...?" an answer containing a concrete algorithm for getting the result you want is considered a full justification. I remember hearing about someone at the [IMO](https://www.imo-official.org/) solving a question about why a knight-like piece on a rectangular chess board couldn't get from one corner to the other. He turned in a solution where he had drawn the chessboard and marked _every single_ square the knight could possibly get to. He got full score (of course, had he missed a single square, it might've given $0$ points).